# Utterance "What is the temperature in the room" always reports device is off

Tags: google-smart-home

I have a device as "Heater" to support the utterance "what is the temperature in the room?", and my instance returns following JSON object of device status to Home Service: {'devices': {'': {'online': True, 'on': True, 'thermostatTemperatureSetpoint': 21, 'thermostatTemperatureAmbient': 29, 'currentModeSettings': {'mode': 'Heating'}, 'currentFanSpeedSetting': 'L1'}}}

But Google always returns " is off and it's curretnly 29 degrees". Does anyone know why Google thinks device is off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your device is generally implementing the [TemperatureSetting](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/temperaturesetting) trait, but your device state seems to use `currentModeSettings` rather than the expected `activeThermostatMode` for the current mode. As such, the `activeThermostatMode` is going to use a default value.

Comment: The "currentModeSettings" is used for other features, and I have added both "thermostatMode" and "activeThermostatMod" which is optional, the result is still same with following object:

{'devices': { <device-id>: {'online': True, 'on': True, 'thermostatTemperatureSetpoint': 21, 'thermostatTemperatureAmbient': 28, 'thermostatMode': 'heat', 'activeThermostatMode': 'heat', 'currentModeSettings': {'mode': 'Heating'}, 'currentFanSpeedSetting': 'L1'}}}

Comment: Have you resynced your devices? Can you try this without the Modes trait at all for the moment?

Comment: Yes, I unlink then link my account before the test, and Modes is a required feature for my project, do you think Home Service confused itself by "currentModeSettings"?

Comment: Yes there can be some odd behavior with thermostats and the Modes trait. Can you use TemperatureControl rather than TemperatureSetting?

Comment: Unfortunately my device is Heater which should use "TemperatureSetting"

Comment: Tested with your suggestion and it works now, it seems Home Service expects the response object only contains the supported attributes by that command, thanks a lot for your help.